# PHP command line output buffer outputs regardless of buffer settings

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have some classes I am writing unit tests for which have echoes in them. I want to suppress this output and thought `ob_start()` and `ob_clean()` would suffice, but they aren't having an effect.

```
public function testSomething (){
    ob_start();
    $class = new MyClass();
    $class->method();
    ob_clean();
}
```

I've also tried variations such as `ob_start(false, 0, true);` and `ob_end_clean()` to no avail.

What am I missing?

Comment: I've got the same issue, I've tried `ob_implicit_flush(false);` and checking the result of `ob_start()` to see if it starts, which apparently it does as it returns true.

Comment: I too am having the same issue. Tried the implicit flush but no dice.

Answer (score 3):

you may want something like this

```
<?php
public function testSomething (){
    ob_start();
    ob_implicit_flush(false); // turn off implicit flush

// Make your output below
    $class = new MyClass();
    $class->method();
// End of output

// store output into variable:
    $output = ob_get_contents();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have [implicit_flush](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.implicit-flush) set to `true` in your PHP ini? This can cause the behaviour you are seeing as it tells PHP to tell the output layer to flush itself automatically after every output block. This is equivalent to calling the PHP function flush() after each and every call to print() or echo() and each and every HTML block.

Comment: It's set to off in php.ini, although it says it's hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI. I've added `ob_implicit_flush(false);` to no effect.

Comment: I am not sure. Perhaps try setting it `false` before calling `ob_start()` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

The following solves this problem for me.  Without calling ob_end_clean(), the contents of the buffer remain until the script's end, where it is flushed.

```
ob_implicit_flush(false);
ob_start();    
/*
  ...
  ... do something that pushes countent to the output buffer
  ...
*/    
$rendered = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); // Needed to clear the buffer
```