# Reading output of git push from PHP exec() function

Tags: php, git, bash, operating-system

I'm writing a deployment command for my framework's command line tool. It uses git to deploy.

I have a line where I do this:

```
exec("git push {$remote} {$branch}:{$branch}", $shell_output, $status);
```

I would like to have the output of the push inside `$shell_output`, but its not happening (The output just shows up on terminal). I think because `git` is an external program and therefore creates a new output stream?

I've tried using an output buffer described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461175/php-command-line-output-buffer-outputs-regardless-of-buffer-settings) to no avail. I'm sure theres something on SO that can answer this, but haven't been able to find it after much digging..

So any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

git sends its output to STDERR not STDOUT so you will need to redirect that with something like this:

`git push REPO --progress 2>&1`

or to a file:

`git push REPO --progress > /path/to/file 2>&1`