# TCL script - exec flush the text to my stdout

Tags: pipe, tcl, exec, stdout

How can I "flush" the `stdout` of the `exec` command to my script's `stdout` without "waiting" for the resulting exec to return?

For instance in the following script I would like the `git clone` output to appear immediately in my script context:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

# git outputs progress of the clone download but it isn't visible in this script's context. How can I flush it? 
exec git clone /path/to/some/repo.git
```

I'm guessing I need some sort of combination of `pipe "|"` and `tee` and file redirection.
Can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the output immediately, you need to open the subcommand as a pipeline. The correct (and not *quite* obvious, for which we apologise) way to do that is with this construction of `open |[list …]`:

```
set mypipeline [open |[list git clone /path/to/some/repo.git]]

# Now to read it by line; we'll just print it out with a line number to show off
set linenum 0
while {[gets $mypipeline line] >= 0} {
    puts "Line [incr linenum]: $line"
}

# Close the pipe now we're at EOF
close $mypipeline
```

Be aware however that some programs (I don't know if `git` is one) change their behaviour when run in a pipeline, buffering their output until they have a full buffer's worth. (It's part of how the C runtime works by default when output isn't to a terminal.) If that's a problem, you will have to run using Expect. That's a large enough topic that you should look for (and ask if necessary) a separate question; it's quite a step change in complexity, alas.

Also be aware that git might well write to its standard error (as noted in this question, [Reading output of git push from PHP exec() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389494/reading-output-of-git-push-from-php-exec-function)) so you might need to merge standard error into the captured standard out (as tersely documented on the [`exec`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) manual page).

```
set output [exec git clone /path/to/some/repo.git 2>@1]
```

```
set mypipeline [open |[list git clone /path/to/some/repo.git 2>@1]]
# ...
```

It's possible to do read/write pipes as well, but rather more complex.

Comment: Very awesome! Thank you. Not sure why the default behavior isn't to output to the screen... Makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not interested in the output of the program in your TCL-program, you could also just redirect the output with the '>@' option of the exec command to a different location, i.e. '>@ stdout' in your case.

Comment: I had trouble with this and found that I also needed to redirect stderr, ie. `exec >@stdout 2>@stderr myprogram`

Answer (score 0):

`exec`'s job is to capture the output of the command, so I don't think you can alter the buffering of it. Here's a test best illustrated in an interactive tclsh session: both these commands wait until the exec'ed process is complete before returning the output, even the one where I've explicitly asked for line buffering

```
exec sh -c {sleep 2; echo a; sleep 2; echo b; sleep 3; echo c}
exec stdbuf --output=L sh -c {sleep 2; echo a; sleep 2; echo b; sleep 3; echo c}
```

You're going to have to open a pipe to the command, then read the output line by line. This prints the output of the above command when it appears:

```
set pipe [open [list "|" sh -c {sleep 2; echo a; sleep 2; echo b; sleep 3; echo c}] r]
while {[gets $pipe line] != -1} {puts $line}
close $pipe
```

What do you mean when you say it "isn't visible in this script's context"? Recall that `exec` *captures* the output. It isn't printed by default. I wonder if you just want

```
puts [exec git clone /path/to/some/repo.git]
```

But if you want to see the text in "real-time", open a pipe and loop over `gets` as demonstrated.