# `exec git clone` is interrupted in tclsh

Tags: git, tclsh

I write a tcl script to retrieve remote repository using `git clone`

```
puts "start"
exec git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/device-tree-xlnx.git
puts "finished"
```

Here is message output

```
> $ tclsh ./t.tcl                                                              
start
Cloning into 'device-tree-xlnx'...
    while executing
"exec git clone git@github.com:Xilinx/device-tree-xlnx.git"
    (file "./t.tcl" line 2)
```

After `git clone` is finished, `puts "finished"` can't be execute.

Has anyone encountered or solved this problem?

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398439/6577998) would answer your question. So if you put `git clone -q` to suppress output or redirect output like `set output [exec git clone /path/to/some/repo.git 2>@1]`, then you'll see your `puts` execute.

Comment: Hi @mnestorov: I add `-q` flag to `git clone`, it's valid! I guess that maybe `git clone` returns such as `stderr` and lead script to exit.

Comment: It's fine when I replace `exec git clone https://github.com/Xilinx/device-tree-xlnx.git` with `exec ls`,

Comment: `git clone` writes to stderr, `ls` does not. You can also redirect `exec git clone ... 2>@1` so that it also behaves as expected.

Comment: In [this](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) documentation, which is also linked to the above answer, is explained why this happens when a program writes to stderr. This can also be suppressed with `-ignorestderr`.

Comment: Hi @mnestorov: thanks! This problem is solved by you. Could you write solution to answer?

Comment: I just curious about the reason why `git clone` return *stderr* even commend execute successfully.

Comment: Read [this](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-push-output-goes-into-stderr-td6758028.html) interesting email conversation. The TL;DR is - stdout is for program specific output and status reports. Progress and other chatter (like the thing `git clone` progress output is doing) is not part of the program output, thus should be pushed to stderr. Stderr is **not** only for errors that the program outputs.